# modal and open new page

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I'm trying to open a modal and when you click on close button, it opens a url on same page.
the code I'm using is:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        //Show modal box
        $('#openModal').click(
            function() {$('.modal').show();}
        );
        //Hide modal box
        $('#closeModal').click(
            function() {$('.modal').hide();
            "location.href='http://google.com'";}
        );
    });
```

Someone?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the code to open the URL is inside double quotes. The statement `"location.href='http://google.com'";` does not do anything.

You instead need:

```
$('#closeModal').click(function() {
    $('.modal').hide();
    location.href='http://google.com';
});
```